# How to remove My.Settings data

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

I've set 4 objects into `MySettings` (Usr1, Usr2, Usr3, Usr4) as  `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`.

I give values to it this way (and it works):

```
For x As Integer = 1 To 4
    If My.Settings.Item("Usr" & x.ToString) Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.Item("Usr" & x.ToString) = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection _
            From {Me.TBox_Name.Text, _
                  Me.Tbox_Surname.Text, _
                  Me.TBox_City.Text, _
                  Me.CBox_Age.Text}
        My.Settings.Save()
        Saved = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

When I try to remove records and set object to nothing I can't match

This is what I'v tryed:

```
Dim ToDelete = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection _
            From {Me.TBox_Name.Text, _
                  Me.Tbox_Surname.Text, _
                  Me.TBox_City.Text, _
                  Me.CBox_Age.Text}
If Not My.Settings.Usr1 Is Nothing AndAlso My.Settings.Usr1.Equals(ToDelete) Then
    My.Settings.Usr1 = Nothing
End If
If Not My.Settings.Usr2 Is Nothing AndAlso My.Settings.Usr2.Equals(ToDelete) Then
    My.Settings.Usr2 = Nothing
End If
If Not My.Settings.Usr3 Is Nothing AndAlso My.Settings.Usr3.Equals(ToDelete) Then
    My.Settings.Usr3 = Nothing
End If
If Not My.Settings.Usr4 Is Nothing AndAlso My.Settings.Usr4.Equals(ToDelete) Then
    My.Settings.Usr4 = Nothing
End If
```

**But I never find equal: nothing matches.**
I tryed getting values from settings and putting them into textboxes. So I'm sure that values in the textboxes are equal to my setting but my code don't recognize it.
Where am I wrong?
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: `Equals` doesnt check each element in the collection for you.  the collection is a reference object so it tests if they are the same object.  they never will be.  You'd better off using something list a List(of User) and serializing it rather than trying to use Settings as a database

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks (your hints are always useful) I've solved looping strings into objects (not a great code but works) P.S. I've started using option strict  ;).

Answer (score -1):

It is a simple command.

```
My.Settings.Usr1.Clear()
```

Comment: But I'm not able to do it! :(

Comment: I apologize, I mixed up clear and reset. Updated my answer

Comment: I've understood this, but how can I find the Usr to clear?

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but please see my edited question: My problem is on comparing data.